# JPA IdGeneration strategy AUTO

Tags: hibernate, jpa, identity, sequence

I want to have an entity with AUTO IdGeneration strategy, I need it work both on Oracle and MySQL, and I need to specify sequence names for each entit in case of Oracle.

When I annotate the primary key as:

```
@Id
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO, generator="sequence")
```

I've got an error on MySQL that sequence generator is unknown.

and if I use

```
@Id
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
```

I can not specify sequence name for each table.
Is it a way to solve this problem?

I use Hibernate as my JPA provider

Answer (score 0):

You declare id field as:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY,
    generator = "LegacyIdGenerator")
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "LegacyIdGenerator",
    strategy = "com.backend.hibernate.PenetratingIdGenerator")
```

where PenetratingIdGenerator is your custom ID generator implemented IdentifierGenerator interface. Now you can generate ID as you want in dependency of your underlying database.
In any way your application will know wich db is underlying because you need define different dialects and etc in config files.

Answer (score 0):

For annotation `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`, the `JPA` persistence provider will take an appropriate strategy for the particular database. For Oracle database, this will be `SEQUENCE` and, if you will not specify anything, Hibernate will use a single global sequence i.e `hibernate_sequence`.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="seq_gen_default")
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq_gen_default", sequenceName="ENTITY_SEQ")
private Long id;
```